# jquery ajax not working when I using asp.net routing with asp.net webforms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, routes

I'm using asp.net routing in my projet with asp.net webforms
but my jquery ajax methoud not working 
how i resolve this problem

me server side methoud is:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string search(List<string> aData)
{
       //my code
       return "resault";
}
```

my client side function is:

```
function search(e) {

    if (e.value == "") {
        //$("#imgLoading").hide();
        $("#search-res").html("");
        $("#search-res").slideUp();
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("#search-res").html("<img src='/content/img/loading (4).gif' alt='Alternate Text' />");


    }
    var aData = [];
    aData[0] = e.value;
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData: aData });



    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/User/default.aspx/search',
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (res) {

            var items = res.d;

            $("#search-res").html(res.d);
            $("#search-res").slideDown();


        },
        error: function (type) {
            alert(type.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

before i use routing my jquery function was working correctly

Comment: alert which is inside error., is that called?? Do you get any failure notification?

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: yes i get http error 404

Comment: Can you post your .Aspx code?

Comment: no because it can not find my url to post

Comment: before i aplly routing in my project the jquery script was working corectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved my problem

i changed my code

```
function search(e) {

    if (e.value == "") {
        //$("#imgLoading").hide();
        $("#search-res").html("");
        $("#search-res").slideUp();
        return;
    }
    else {
        $("#search-res").html("<img src='/content/img/loading (4).gif' alt='Alternate Text' />");


    }
    var aData = [];
    aData[0] = e.value;
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ aData: aData });


    var Url='/User/Default.aspx/search'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Url,
        data: jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (res) {

            var items = res.d;

            $("#search-res").html(res.d);
            $("#search-res").slideDown();


        },
        error: function (type) {
            alert(type.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```